# Python - Decode Text (German) from Hexadecimal Value and write it to a file

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding, utf-8, decoding

I know there are a lot of encoding/decoding topics here and I tried it for hours, but I'm still not able to solve it. Hence I want to raise a question:

I have a string with hexadecimal values, which in the end is a text that I want to write to a text file with the correct encoding.

```
hexvalues = "476572E2A47465646574656B746F72"
```

In the end, the (german) result should be "**Gerätedetektor**"

Currently I am using `binascii.unhexlify()` for the decoding, but it still doesn't show me the "ä" like its supposed to be, and instead, I get:

```
>> result = binascii.unhexlify(hexvalues)
Gerâ¤tedetektor
```

I tried to do `result.decode("utf-8")` and a lot of other things but either the script crashes or it also doesn't return what I want to see.

In the end, I want to write the word in the correct way to a file.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Edit:
As I wrote before, I tried many things so it is kind of hard to give the ONE code that I'm using but here is an excerpt from the current version:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import binascii


resultfile = "text_GER.txt"
fpx = open(resultfile, 'wb')
hexvalues = "476572E2A47465646574656B746F72"

result= binascii.unhexlify(hexvalues )
result= result.decode("utf-8")
print(result)
fpx.write(result)
```

This one makes the script crash, but no further indicators why it does.

If i skip

```
result= result.decode("utf-8")
```

then my result print of result looks like this:

```
b'Ger\xe2\xa4tedetektor'
```

Comment: Checking those hex codes, it should be UTF8. Add your utf-8 based code and we might see what you did wrong there. If a Python program crashes, it usually tells you why it did so, so add that text to your question as well.

Comment: Thanks! Edited, even though i constantly change the code now as Im trying everything. But this should give you an idea

Comment: Thanks, Ill try to figure out how to do it exactly, but before i do that: isnt the idea of converting the bytes object to a string in contrast to my idea of writing it to a file? Because in my current version, the text was also incorrect for the files. Btw, Im using Python 3.6.

Comment: That is weird. It is *not* UTF8 at all. Do you have any hints on what it possibly could be instead? Can you add a link to the original data file?

Comment: This is not any of the 98 builtin codecs that python 3.6 supports. Without further information where the data came from, it's just anybody's guess. The german umlaut "ä" is encoded as `e4` in UTF8, represented as `e2a4` here; the high and low nibbles might be coincidence, maybe it's a custom escaping sequence at play here.

Comment: Looks like there is an incorrect hex byte when composing the string. See the output of ```[ hex(ord(x)) for x in b'Gerätedetektor' ]```. The 4th byte is different: ```['0x47', '0x65', '0x72', '0xc3', '0xa4', '0x74', '0x65', '0x64', '0x65', '0x74', '0x65', '0x6b', '0x74', '0x6f', '0x72']```.

Comment: Well, your character has 8 bytes, but I also don't think it's UTF-8. I decoded it manually and it gave me: *åÅHèÊÈÊèÊÖèÞr*

Comment: The Hex values are accurate and as is. I get it from a game that im datamining after some deobfuscation. It is working for all other characters, so the method itself is working. I am thinking if the publisher of the game just uses their own codec? I think i will just write a small function that replaces the letters. e.g. \xe2\xa4 -> ä

Comment: Or that is just another layer of obfuscation perhaps.

Comment: It looks more like [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake).  The correct bytes for `ä` are `b'\xc3\xa4'` in UTF-8.  `E2` in UTF-8 is the start of a 3-byte sequence, which is unlikely in German.  It's not as if mistakes like this aren't made all the time.

Comment: But its definitely a german word an everytime i expect an "ä" it comes exactly with these bytes.